# What is the difference between CAO and SAO in Remoting?

Tags: c#, .net, object, remoting

What is the difference between **CAO(Client-activated objects )** and **SAO(Server-activated objects)** in Remoting?

Hoping for some good answers clearing citing the differences. any links or explanations are welcome. 
I have googled about this but there wasnt much good answers in it either.

Comment: Were you aware that Remoting is an obsolete technology?

Comment: Maybe i would have to start a bounty!!

Comment: But still i need to know the differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of an remote class can be activated by either the server or client.

**Client-activated objects** are created on the server as soon as the client calls New or the Activator object.

(*Basically, each client-activated instance of a remote class has a 1:1 mapping with a particular client. Each client holds its own personal instance of the remote class.*)

**Server-activated objects** are created by the server only when the client invokes the first method through the local proxy.

(*server-activated objects can be declared as Singleton or SingleCall objects. A Singleton object has exactly one instance to serve all possible clients. A SingleCall object requires that each incoming call is served by a new instance.*)

Please check the below 2002 MSDN magazine about remoting. But as advised by @John Saunders, you should better use WCF. In WCF, you don't need to learn different technologies for **webservices**, **remoting** or **messaging** communication. These are all under the umbrella of WCF.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188927.aspx#S6